# Negative infinitive as reason in the beginning of sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is it correct to say *Not to leave him alone, we took him with us too*?

I think it's OK to say to put reason to the end: *We took him with us too not to leave him alone*.

What are other options?

Comment: It's "To not leave him alone", not "Not to leave him alone". Another option would be "We took him with us, so that we didn't leave him alone".

Comment: @MorganFR Thanks! Is it called "split infinitive"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called "[fronting](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/fronting)" in English grammar when you want to change a normal or common word order in order to emphasize *adjuncts* or *complements*.

> Some elements like adjuncts or complements do not typically belong at
>   the beginning of a clause. When we want to focus on them, we bring
>   them to the front or beginning of the clause. We often find this in
>   written literary or formal contexts.

To infinitive in your example indicates "purpose" of the action "to take" and it modifies the action. It is grammatically correct to *front* the to-infinitive.

Whether it should be "not to leave him alone" or "to not leave him alone" is controversial and both seem to be okay. However, for some idiomatic expressions such as "[not to mention](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/101283-Not-to-mention)", it is not okay to use "to not mention".

As MorganFR mentioned, change the "to infinitive" to "so that clause" is another option:

> So that he wouldn't be left alone (So that we didn't leave him alone), we took him with us too.
>
> We took him with us too so that he wouldn't be left alone (so that we didn't leave him alone).